# Need information on dataproc image version 1.5.54

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Where can I check for information on dataproc image version 1.5.54 and verify that it is not vulnerable to the log4j RCE? In the dataproc [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes), 1.5.53 is listed as the latest release from December.

When launching dataproc clusters with image version 1.5-ubuntu18 which automatically picks the latest 1.5.x image, we noticed that dataproc was using images with subminor version 1.5.54-ubuntu18 when we were expecting 1.5.53 as per the release page. The web console also has a warning message for all 1.5.54 dataproc cluster that this version is vulnerable to log4j exploit and that we should be using a newer image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes for 1.4.78, 1.5.54 and 2.0.28 have just been published [1](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#January_09_2022). The images come with log4j 2.17.0, which doesn't have the vulnerability.

The warning message is a false signal, the Dataproc team is working to remove it. Sorry for the confusion!